# Min value from Database in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Am trying to find the min value from past 30 days, in my table there is one entry for every day, am using this query

```
SELECT MIN(low), date, low 
FROM historical_data 
WHERE name = 'bitcoin' 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

But this value not returing the correct value. The structure of my table is

Table structure
[image]

And table data which is store is like this

Table data style
[image]

Now what i need is to get the minimum low value. But my query not working it give me wrong value which even did not exist in table as well.

**Updates:**

Here is my updated Table Structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcfrx.png)

And here is my data in this table which look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0KUU.png)

Now if you look at the data, i want to check the name of token `omisego` and fatch the low value from past 7 days which will be from `2017-12-25` to `2017-12-19`
and in this cast the low value is `9.67`, but my current query and the query suggested by my some member did not brings the right answer.

**Update 2:**

```
http://rextester.com/TDBSV28042
```

Here it is, basically i have more then `1400` `coins` and `token` historical data, which means that there will me more then 1400 entries for same date like `2017-12-25` but having different name, total i have more then `650000` records. so every date have many entries with different names.

Comment: your post looks to be a repost of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966447/calculate-volatility-ratio-of-historical-data-of-cryptocurrency-market-capitaliz

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner not they are totally different, in previous question i calculate volatility ratio which is different thing, and here am getting low value, there are totally different direction. how you say they are same am shook

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner check the formula which is use to calculate the volatility ration.

Comment: Please add your expected result set, Moreover you have used an aggregate function `min()` with out `group by`  clause this will return you single row considering all records as a single group, So limit 7 is of not use Please update your question with exactly what values/data you want

Comment: Date in a VARCHAR ?? Not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lowest row per group you could use following

```
SELECT a.*
FROM historical_data a 
LEFT JOIN historical_data b ON a.name = b.name 
AND a.low > b.low
WHERE b.name IS NULL
AND DATE(a.date) >= '2017-12-19' AND DATE(a.date) <= '2017-12-25' 
AND a.name = 'omisego'
```

or

```
SELECT a.*
FROM historical_data a 
JOIN (
    SELECT name,MIN(low) low
    FROM historical_data
    GROUP BY name
) b USING(name,low)
WHERE  DATE(a.date) >= '2017-12-19' AND DATE(a.date) <= '2017-12-25' 
AND a.name = 'omisego'
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/UFYGK40202)

For last 30 day of 7 days or n days you could write above query as

```
SELECT a.*, DATE(a.`date`)
FROM historical_data2 a 
LEFT JOIN historical_data2 b ON a.name = b.name 
AND DATE(b.`date`) >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
AND DATE(b.`date`) <= CURRENT_DATE()
AND a.low > b.low
WHERE b.name IS NULL
AND a.name = 'omisego'
AND DATE(a.`date`) >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
AND DATE(a.`date`) <= CURRENT_DATE()
;
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/TTLQ57486)

But note it may return more than one records where low value is same, to choose 1 row among these you have specify another criteria to on different attribute

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i find a loop whole. as i have multiple entries for same date but with different names, then it not showing me any result.

Comment: @SaraTariq  can you add sample data here http://rextester.com and add your expected data also in your question , From above comment its not clear what is the exact issue

Comment: @SaraTariq i have removed data filter have a look at http://rextester.com/BHAPH90206 does this works for you ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, i need that filter as well. so that i can check lowest values in past 7 days, 30days or what every range i select.

Comment: @SaraTariq See the update answer and another issue for same low value for morethan 1 rows which row should be returned

Answer (score 0):

Consider grouping the same and running the clauses

```
SELECT name, date, MIN(low)
FROM historical_data 
GROUP BY name
HAVING name = 'bitcoin' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%M %d,%Y') > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Given the structure, the above query should get you your results.

Comment: it get the low value but not from last 30 days. it give overall low value

Comment: this did not return any thing.

Comment: Issue! Date is a VARCHAR

Comment: Correct @RiggsFolly.
The data for date field should be of type "datetime" to avoid additional overhead.

Comment: @SaraTariq did the updated query work for you? It will give you the result based on the last 30 days records.

Comment: @ValerianPereira Thanks for your help i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

// Try this code ..

```
SELECT MIN(`date`) AS date1,low
        FROM historical_data
 WHERE `date` BETWEEN now() - interval 1 month 
                  AND now() ORDER by low ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks. it show me right date which have lowest value, but the value is not correct it picking the wrong value. means value did not match with date that are showing

Comment: Please change data format in query .. date is not compare because your date format is change .... now() function is fetch default date structure ...

Comment: i have change the format, you can check it in update section, now date format is datetime

Comment: i already done it, check my update question, i have new images uploaded.